# How do I delete firewall rules with pf.conf? OSX Yosemite. -For split tunneling Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: osx-yosemite, cisco-vpn-client, split-tunnel

I'm trying to follow these instructions to use split tunneling with my Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client connection. The VPN server is configured to not allow split tunneling and we cannot change that on the server's end, so we have to do it on the client's end.

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/753.cfm

These instructions are fine, except that `ipfw` has been replace with `pf` in Yosemite. So I need to know how to delete the firewall setting in Yosemite using `pf`.

Any help will be very much appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this issue, it turns out the Yosemite still actually does use ipfw under the covers via socket options, just get the ipfw from an older mac and copy it over to your box. You can verify this by looking at /var/log/system.log after Cisco AnyConnect is connected it's still setting the ipfw rules. I just copied over the ipfw binary and used it directly and the problem was solved again.